# iOS Launch Screen Animation Time

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

It seems like the fade animation between the launch screen and my first view is really slow.

I don't think it used to be like that. Is there a way to control the speed of that transitional animation?

I looked at some apps on my phone and the launch screen doesn't fade as slowly as mine. What things could I have done to affect that?

(No I don't have slow animations turned on, only the fade animation is slow)

Comment: Are you referring to the launch image animation or launch xib animation?

Comment: @MirekE I'm not sure the difference between the two you mentioned. I'm talking about the animation that fades from the launch image to the first view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out what was going on here, but the next day when I started up xCode and the simulator it was back to the normal loading time.

Answer (score 0):

In WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Responsiveness](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=235) they enumerate a whole list of issues that have impact on the app startup time, ranging from attaching to unnecessary frameworks, optional linking to frameworks that you really could make required, the use of static initializers, overly complicated initial scenes, too much information stored in preferences, etc.

That video covers a range of topics, like the above, which impact startup time. In the demonstration, they show how one might benchmark the startup time. Unfortunately, in my experience, there's a good chance that you might not be able to do anything to fix this issue (e.g. you need certain features and therefore need certain frameworks), but it's still an illuminating video and it might give you some ideas of things you can try to alleviate the start-up performance issues.

Comment: This is a good video. However, I'm not talking about app startup time. Just the animation--how long it takes for launch image to fade out.

Answer (score 0):

If your app splash screen show more time, so please check following things in your app.
1. AppDelegate.m 
in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method have you called any heavy method which takes more time for finish task if yes then change that method location, basically in appDelegate class don't write any heavy methods.
2. first view of your app. 
check viewDidLoad() method, if you call many method or any heavy method from here then your launch image will show still your control not come out from viewDidLoad method, so if you want call any methods at view launch time then call them from viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method (in viewDidAppear method don't call any UI related methods)